# Forgot name of tool for theoretical measure of form interactions

Tags: forms, tools

A few years ago I used a tool that could theoretically measure the time to complete a form. The way it works is that you click on e.g. a screenshot, and mark what is a label, what is an input field, expected input etc. The tool would then calculate time spend on eye-movement (reading the label, identifying field etc), the time to move hand from mouse to keyboard, time to enter input etc.

I cannot find the tool anywhere, and I cannot remember what it was called.

Does anyone know the tool? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a software that can automatically analyse [GOMS models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOMS). Should've guessed there are tools for that but it didn't ever occur to me to search for them.

GOMS's Wikipedia page mentions two of them: GogTool (https://cogtool.wordpress.com/) and Cogulator (http://cogulator.io/).

Comment: Yes...absolutely....spot on....thank you so much :)